# Sum every second value in a vector starting from the third entry

Tags: r

I woud like to apply the following function to a vector instead of a matrix where the vector consists of >100 entries and I would like to add them starting from the third element and adding every second element.

```
apply(vector,1,function(x) sum(x[seq(3,length(x),2)]))
```

A quick example would be:

```
a: 123 4 100 3 594 5 302 ....
```

What would be added is 100+594+302+...

Comment: What's the input, what's the expected result? We don't have your `vector` (yet). Btw, have you tried `sum(vector[seq(3,length(vector),2)])`?

Comment: Why use apply? Why not just sum(x[seq(3,length(x), by=2)])

Comment: `sum(vector[seq[3, length(vector), by=2]])` doesn't work for you? Or are you asking how to apply this function to all values in the vector? If so: `sapply(1:length(vector), function(i) sum(vector[seq[i + 2, length(vector), by=2]]))`. Please explain what you are asking, in case I have not understood it correctly.

Comment: no its working perfectly, the problem is resolved. someone can enter the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
v <- 1:10 # an example vector

sum(v[-1][c(FALSE, TRUE)])
# [1] 24
```